# Effective variance for two independent variables

Tags: variance, fitting

When you're fitting a model $y=f(x)$ to data (${x_i, y_i}$) with errorbars on both the independent ($x$) and response ($y$) variables, it's standard that you can define an 'effective variance' when calculating the chi-squared

$$(\delta y_i)^2 + \left(\delta x_i \left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)_{x=x_i} \right)^2$$

Here the differential is evaluated at the value of $x_i$ of interest.

My question is if this can be extended to the case where there are two independent variables $(x, z)$, so that you're fitting a function $y=g(x, z)$. Something like:

$$(\delta y_i)^2 + \left(\delta x_i \left(\frac{dg}{dx}\right)_{x=x_i} \right)^2 + \left(\delta z_i \left(\frac{dg}{dz}\right)_{z=z_i} \right)^2$$

Comment: Is f a function? If so, a function of what. Can you explain what dy, dx are. I assume df/dx is a derivative of the function f. The formula here http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Leo/Stats7_3.html is similar but has differences. Please be more precise

Comment: I've edited some things to hopefully make it clearer. The link you've supplied is the one variable case.

Comment: Where is _effective variance_ standard? In which field of study?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. It's a common tool used in model fitting. Here's a paper - www.jrossmacdonald.com/jrmpubs/192LSFITTING.pdf